# I see empty canvass while using Folium in Databricks

Tags: python, iframe, databricks, folium

I am seeing blank HTML canvass while using Folium in Databricks. I am using python 3.5

I have installed all the required packages in the Databricks cluster.

```
import folium
folium_map = folium.Map([-87.634362, 41.894722], zoom_start = 12)

width =100
height =400
html_string = folium_map._repr_html_()

# for python 3.5

h = '<iframe srcdoc = {html_string} width ={width} height ={height} > </iframe>'.format(html_string = html_string, width =width, height =height)

displayHTML(h)
```

I expect to see a map at the canvass. Right now, it has an empty canvass.
I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your srcdoc in quotation marks, as in:

`h = "<iframe srcdoc = '{html_string}' width ={width} height ={height} > </iframe>".format(html_string = html_string, width =width, height =height)`

Also, I would suggest you use the f-string for Python > 3.6 (which is now supported on ML clusters >= 5.4 in Databricks):

`h = f"<iframe srcdoc='{html_string}' width={width} height={height} ></iframe>"`

Comment: i found that single quotation mark doesnot work rather need to use double quotation as you mentioned up. Thanks Shum!